# ROCK-PAPER-SCISSORS ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a rock-paper-scissors game. this is what I have so far. I am having trouble with the function determineOutcome. I an trying to get the outcome to return the computers outcome as rock, paper, or scissors. not the randomNumber(), 1, 2, or 3. I would really appreciate your help. this is my code:

```
btnPlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playGame);
btnNewGame.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, newGame);

var ties:int = 0;
var wins:int = 0;
var losses:int = 0;

function playGame(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var userThrow:int;
    var computerThrow:int;
    var outcome:String;

    userThrow = int(radRock.group.selectedData);
    computerThrow = randomWholeNumber(3,1);
    outcome = determineOutcome(userThrow, computerThrow);

    lblOutcome.text = outcome;  
    lblScore.text = "Wins: " + wins.toString() + "  Losses: " + losses.toString() + "Ties: " + ties.toString();
}


function newGame(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //
}


function randomWholeNumber(highNumber:int,lowNumber:int):int
{
    return Math.floor((highNumber - lowNumber + 1) * Math.random() + lowNumber);
}


function determineOutcome(u:int,c:int):String
{
    if(u == 2 && c == 1){
        return "The computer threw a rock and your paper covered it. You Win!"
    }

    else if(u == 3 && c == 2){
        return "The computer threw paper and your scissors cut the paper.You Win!"
    }

    else if(u == 1 && c == 3){
        return "The computer threw scissors and your rock smashed it. You Win!"
    }

    else if(u == c){
        return "You tied with the computer"
    }

    else if(u == 1 && c == 2){
        return "you threw a rock and the Computer's paper covered it. You lose :("
    }

    else if(u == 2 && c == 3){
        return "You threw paper and the Computer's scissors cut your paper.You lose :("
    }

    else if(u == 3 && c == 1){
        return "You threw scissors and the Computer's rock smashed it. You lose :("
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function would throw a compiler error because it doesn't return a value by default. By that I mean is that there is no return statement outside of a conditional. You always need a return statement outside in case one of the conditions aren't met. At the very end, just add return ""; or return null;

Comment: i am also having trouble with the newgame function. i want the player to press the new game button and have the label score clear all the added points, but the score isnt even kept in the first place. how would i get the score to be kept.

Comment: With this code, you would have to add to the score depending on the outcome. Within the appropriate brackets write (before the return statement) `losses++` or `wins++` etc. This adds 1 to the variable. 

If you want to reset it, just set those variables to zero.

Comment: that worked. but im still a little confused about the function newGame(). the variables are already set to 0.